# Showing progress bar while fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, html, progress-bar

I have just started using HTML5, so I went through its new attribute and came up to the progress bar feature. I want to implement it with my PHP and MySQL report. I would like to show the progress bar while the row gets fetched from my query into the php report so can any one help in showing of how it can be done ???
Here is my simple report code:

```php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

/***My report code**/
}

<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: Can you post your ajax request code?

Comment: well that was just a sample query i just want to knw of how could i place the exact value from the query to the progress element so that the progress element could be shown properly

Comment: I think you can find that answer here: [Progress bar while running while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353914/progress-bar-while-running-while-loop)

Comment: can u tell how many rows are there? in that case i can help you